# SASS - get previous items width and add variable onto it

Tags: css, sass

I am try to access the previous item in a list using SASS so that I can add my variable $itemWidthIncrement onto the previous items value hence having an increment of 3px for each item:

```
$totalItems: 12;
$itemWidthIncrement: 3px;
$itemMarginIncrement: 1px;

@for $i from 1 through $totalItems {
  .item-:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        float: if($i % 2 == 0, left, right);
        width:/*get previous item here*/ + $itemWidthIncrement;
   }
}
```

Is this doable with SASS or am I not approaching this in the correct manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - keep a `$currentWidth` variable and increment as necessary:

```
$totalItems: 12;
$itemWidthIncrement: 3px;
$itemMarginIncrement: 1px;
$currentWidth: 1px;

@for $i from 1 through $totalItems {
  .item-:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        float: if($i % 2 == 0, left, right);
        width: $currentWidth;
   }
   $currentWidth: $currentWidth + $itemWidthIncrement;
}
```

Comment: Almost! - how do I make the first item start at 1?